# Find out the training error after fit()

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm training a [LinearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) model and I want to get the training error of it. Is it possible to get it w/o evaluating it manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sklearn is using [liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) for this task.

You can take a quick glance into the sources [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/svm/classes.py#L231):

```
self.coef_, self.intercept_, self.n_iter_ = _fit_liblinear(
    X, y, self.C, self.fit_intercept, self.intercept_scaling,
    self.class_weight, self.penalty, self.dual, self.verbose,
    self.max_iter, self.tol, self.random_state, self.multi_class,
    self.loss, sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

which shows that only coefficients, intercepts and number of iterations are processed by sklearn's python-API. Whatever else is available in liblinear's output is not grabbed. You can't directly read out the training-error without changing the internal code.

There might be a possible hack turning on verbose-mode, redirect the output and parse additional info available there. But this assumes the info you look for is available there and it's also hacky and i won't recommend it.

Just use the [score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.score)-method. It won't be too costly compared to fitting.

Comment: Depends on the metric in use. It's at least: higher score better; lower error better. Everything else is more complex (in the general case). The score-method above is also mean-accuracy only (according to the docs). You probably want to use one of [these](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html), which follows the same API, but are external static functions, not class-methods like clf.score().